# Create functions at runtime with swift

Tags: swift

How can I create a function or method at runtime using Swift? Is there an equivalent command like eval? I would like to be able to do something like:

```
eval("func x(){ println();}")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that it's not an interpreted language, I don't think you can. `C` for instance, has no `eval` since the C compiler is not part of the compiled binary.

But I'm sure there are lots of other (read: better) ways to accomplish that goal that you think you need `eval` for. Whatever that is...

Comment: I wasn't sure from the docs whether the language is interpreted or compiled. Thanks Alex!

Comment: Yep, it's very compiled. Under Swift's fancy syntax is the same toolchain that powers ObjectiveC.

Comment: Then again, LLVM is used by Apple's new superfast FTL JavaScript interpreter. I think we may eventually see an embeddable Swift interpreter, as it appears to be designed to work as a scripting language, and the developers seem to like their REPLs and playgrounds.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson it's possible, but nothing in the current documentation seems to indicate support for this level of dynamism.